# Deploy a PowerShell Script through a GPO

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, group-policy

I have created a PowerShell Script that creates a VPN profile and applied it to a computer through a computer based GPO using a Security filtering.
Through Gpresult on the target computer I can see that the GPO has been applied, but I don't see that the script has been started, or if it did, I don't see the VPN profile created. No error message either.
I've been testing the script, and if I run it manually, it creates the requested profile.
Thank you.

Comment: You need to specify how the GPO is configured. Is it a startup script?

Comment: @GregAskew Yes, it is.

Comment: Startup scripts will not work as expected if a system is not configured to wait for the network connection at startup. It's also a good idea to have the file copied local, instead of running it directly from sysvol. You may want to try a GPO managed scheduled task.

Comment: @GregAskew What do you mean by " wait for the network connection"? In the same GPO, I did setup "Configure Logon Script Delay" to 1 minute.

Comment: There are other policy settings. System > Group Policy > Specify startup policy processing wait time. System > Logon > Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon. You can confirm what is occurring by enabling Group Policy Environment Debug Logging, and reviewing the log. It will show if the system connected to execute the script or not.

Comment: @GregAskew. Thank you, those last settings helped me. Everything's fine now. I'm just wondering, since it's a script that creates a VPN connection, is it possible that it will be run only once?